# How to download files from URL not displaying the filename using perlscript

Tags: perl, download

I'm new to perl script and I'm currently building a perl script which will download a file from a URL. But the file name is not displayed in the URL, like the example URL below:

http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/download/c35606d3b96a03d7941f656b50923c09/

How can I download the file and save it to my local folder(ex. c:\desktop\files) using perl script? Also, how can I bypass the download window in IE and automatically save it in my local folder?(the open,save or cancel window)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you click the [image: download symbol] download symbol on that page, the file will download right away. I think that the URL you should download from perl is the one attacehd to that image. For the page you gave as an example,

```
http://www.filehippo.com/download/file/cb316da24bb57e95894ed734de4455aa95865d6e56f8778ee37b9899455e333d/
```

From perl, you might be able to dependably find this link because it appears in the following format:

```
<div class="downloading">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class="img">
    <a href="/download/file/cb316da24bb57e95894ed734de4455aa95865d6e56f8778ee37b9899455e333d/">
     <img alt="" src="http://cache.filehippo.com/img/download.png" />
    </a>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div class="downloadingTxt">Your program is now downloading
   </td></div>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

#### Edit

Sorry, forgot the second part. To do the downloading, you'll want to use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4670489/1586229):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.filehippo.com/download/file/cb316da24bb57e95894ed734de4455aa95865d6e56f8778ee37b9899455e333d/';

#get file name
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$cnt = %{%{$ua->head( $url )}->{'_headers'}}->{'content-disposition'};
$cnt =~ m/filename=(.*)/;
print "File name is: $1\n";

getstore($url, "/path/to/file/$1");
```

Comment: But what if I dont know the filename? or filetype of the file. Also, how can I specify where to save the file?

Comment: I found an example of how to find the filename [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8788698/1586229). You have to inspect one of the headers. You can specify where to save the file using the $file variable. I'll change the code to show an example.

Comment: the file name is not displayed and also the file is not saved

Comment: I don't really know perl, but the filename can be found from that header. Try the example at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782813/perl-resolving-link-download-name/8788698#8788698) and see if that helps you.